# return outter variable from callback is not work

Tags: node.js, express, callback, functional-programming, passport.js

I need to return result from userService.signIn() with new state
but the return still `{ httpStatus: 500, message: undefined, errorMessage: undefined }`

How can I get the current result?

```
{
  httpStatus: 200,
  message: {
    auth: true,
    token,
    message: 'user found & logged in' 
  }
}
```

```
// user-service.js

module.exports = (db) => {
  return {
    signIn: function (req, res, next) {
      const result = { httpStatus: 500, message: undefined, errorMessage: undefined };
      passport.authenticate('local-comparePassword', {}, (err, user, info) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
        if (info !== undefined) {
          console.error(`Info Message Error: ${info.message}`);
          if (info.message !== 'Username or Password is incorrect') {
            console.log(info.message)
            result.httpStatus = 401;
            result.errorMessage = info.message;
          } else if (!user) {
            console.log(info.message)
            result.httpStatus = 204;
            result.message = 'User not found';
          } else {
            console.log(info.message)
            result.httpStatus = 400;
            result.errorMessage = info.message;
          }
        } else {
          const token = jwt.sign(
            { id: user.id, role: user.role, name: user.name },
            jwtOptions.secretOrKey,
            { expiresIn: 3600 }
          );

          result.httpStatus = 200;
          result.message = {
            auth: true,
            token,
            message: 'user found & logged in'
          };
        }
        return result;
      })(req, res, next);

      // return result
    },
  }
}
```

```
// user-controller.js
module.exports = (db) => {
  return {
    signIn: async (req, res, next) => {
      try {
        const result = await userService(db).signIn(req, res, next)
        console.log('result', result) **// result undefined**
        if (res.httpStatus === 200 || result.httpStatus === 400 || result.httpStatus === 401) {
          res.status(result.httpStatus).json({ message: result.message });
        } else {
          res.status(result.httpStatus).json({ errorMessage: 'error' });
        }
      } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex.message);
        res.status(400).json({ errorMessage: ex.message })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did not run your code, but as I see it:

1. Why did your commented out `return result` in `userService().signIn()` ? Thus **`// result undefined`**. Ok, let's assume that your code is a little bit out of sync with your question.
2. But if your will `return result` from `userService().signIn()` (as you should) it will be in no vain - `passport.authenticate()` calls your callback asynchronously **after** `userService().signIn()` returns
3. `return result` inside of passport.authenticate() callback will return result to passport.authenticate(), not to your `userService().signIn()`, and again, it will happen **after** `signIn` returns
4. Your must declare `signIn` as `async function(...)` - there is no sense in `await` with a function that do not return a `Promise`
5. For that you also need to convert `passport.authenticate()` itself into an async function. Something like this:

   ```
   new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       passport.authenticate(..., (err, user, info) => {
           // ...
           if (err) reject(err);
           if (user) resolve(user);
       }
   }
   ```
6. and then you can

   ```
   signIn: async function(req, res, next) {
     const result = { httpStatus: 500, message: undefined, errorMessage: undefined }
     return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       passport.authenticate(..., (err, user, info) => {
         // ...
         resolve(result);
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   and then

   ```
   await userService(db).signIn()
   ```